# Create a square array with Pascal

Tags: arrays, matrix, pascal

I need to create a program that shows a square matrix (array) with 20 lines and 20 columns and then gives you the maximum and the minimum of this matrix.

I started with this code:

```
program ex2dimarray;
var
    a: array [0..20, 0..20] of integer;
    i, j: integer;

begin
    for i := 0 to 3 do
        for j := 0 to 3 do
            a[i,j] := i * j;

    for i := 0 to 3 do
    begin
        for j := 0 to 3 do
            write(a[i,j]:2, ' ');
        writeln;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question, other than *i need help*?

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? E.g., do you get an error message when trying to compile it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You declare an array of 20x20 but in your code you are using only a 3x3 block. Besides, the logic for finding the max and the min values is missing.

You can try something like this:

```
program ex2dimarray;
const 
    Dim = 20;

var
    a: array [0..Dim, 0..Dim] of integer;
    i, j, min, max: integer;

begin
    // initialize the array
    for i := 0 to Dim do
    begin
        for j := 0 to Dim do
            a[i,j] := i * j;
    end;

    // search for max and min. You can initialize both to a[0,0]
    min:= maxint;
    max:= -maxint;

    for i := 0 to Dim do
    begin
        for j := 0 to Dim do
        begin
            if (a[i,j] > max) then
                max := a[i,j];

            if (a[i,j] < min) then
                min := a[i,j];
        end;
    end;

    // print out the values
    for i := 0 to Dim do
    begin
        for j := 0 to Dim do
            write(a[i,j]:3, ' ');
        writeln;
    end;
    writeln;
    write('Max: ', max, '     Min: ', min);
    writeln;
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: I Get an error on line  9 and 10 
 Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but = found

Comment: @HamzaBounezra What compiler and what version are you using?

Comment: i use Dev-Pascal 1.9.2 i tried Free pascal also the same error

Comment: @HamzaBounezra Try now...

Comment: error in line 36 'write("Max: ", max, "     Min: ", min);' 
 Fatal: illegal character '"' ($22)

Comment: @HamzaBounezra I guess you should use ' instead of "

Comment: @HamzaBounezra It works well [here](https://ideone.com/NERa0j). What error do you have now?

Comment: line 12
 Error: Incompatible types: got "S80REAL" expected "LONGINT"

Comment: i have compiled it with another compiler it works without an error but when i run it the console window close immediatly

Comment: @HamzaBounezra Add a readln before the last end. It also seems that the number I used was too big for an integer type in your environment. If the last fix doesn't work, initialize both variables to the first element of the array.

Comment: Thank you for your help the readln; fixed the problem but the matrice is not orgnized check the image http://imgur.com/zGhplsx

Comment: @HamzaBounezra Enlarge the window... The program is printing 21*4 chars per line...

Comment: its fixed thank you very much @Bob__ you saved me it was the size of the consol window (cmd.xe)

Answer (score 0):

```
program ex2dimarray;

var
 a: array [0..20, 0..20] of integer;
 m, i, j: integer;

begin

//filling the array, in any way you like

for i := 0 to 19 do
    for j := 0 to 19 do
        a[i,j] := i * j;


//scanning for max value

m :=0;
for i := 0 to 19 do
    for j := 0 to 19 do
       if m<=a[i,j] then m:=a[i,j] ;

//print the array

for i := 0 to 19 do
begin
    for j := 0 to 19 do
        write(a[i,j]:2, ' ');
    writeln;
end;

//print the max value

writeln('Maximum is ',m);

end.
```

Comment: error if m<=a[i,j] then m:=a[i.j] ;

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: its good now thank you very mach

Comment: how to add the Min value

Comment: For the min value, you made two modifications :

Comment: 1. Instead of m:=0; it will be m:=a[0,0];

Comment: 2. Invert the inequality: m<=a[I,j]; becomes m>=a[I,j];

Comment: it's working thank you so much @DrWael بارك الله فيك

Comment: بارك الله فيك أخي حمزة :)